# Optaplanner - Can we specify the sequence order for visits or add dependency/relation constraints to the visit

Tags: optaplanner

#### I have four customer visits A, B, C, D after calling the optaplanner solve method i got the optimal solution like as below

#### B -> C -> A -> D

But in my use case we need to arrive VISIT_C after completion of VISIT_B and VISIT_A

Comment: In order to get the behavior you describe, you need to write a constraint that will penalize (or reward) the behavior that you want to see happen. This is as specific as I can be with the information you provided.

Comment: This smells like [Vehicle Routing with mixed pickups and delivery](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment).

Comment: Thank you @GeoffreyDeSmet
Yes, but in mixed VRP solution we can restrict pickup or delivery visits, but in my scenario we need to add multiple dependencies(before/after visits) to customer visit
Example::
https://docs.graphhopper.com/#operation/asyncVRP
Routes optimisation api in graphhopper. In this API they are maintaining relations like in_same_route, in_sequence or in_direct_sequence.
 payload::
{
   "type": "in_same_route",
   "ids": ["serv_i_id","serv_j_id"]
}